# Convergence of infinite series-1

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

To investigate the convergence/divergence of this series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (n^{-1/2}-\sin(n^{-1/2}))^{1/2}   $$

So, I took the maclaurin series$$ \sin(x)\sim x-\frac{x^3}{3!}  $$
Replacing it in the initial equation we get:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (n^{-3/2})^{1/2} $$

which is divergent, by p-series since p=3/4<1.

Is this sufficient to say that the original series is divergent?

Comment: No, you have to make pore precise the sign $\sim$.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean by "pore precise"

Comment: He means "more precise", it was a typo. You must make sufficiently precise what $\sin x \sim x - \frac{x^3}{3!}$ means to draw the conclusion.

Comment: Adding more terms or saying that x $\approx$ 0; what does he mean by more precise? in what sense?

Comment: Something like "$\frac{x^3}{12} < x - \sin x < \frac{x^3}{6}$ for $0 < x < 1$", which would suffice.

Comment: But, how does that change things? Are you opting towards DCT?

Comment: Are you trying to know if your solution is correct, or to argue that it is correct? If the latter, do not pretend the former.

Comment: Why are you becoming antagonistic? I am just asking where I went wrong, and why it needs a correction? I don't understand how the the bounding of x-sin(x) makes it sufficient

Comment: If I include the additional terms then it would make things tricky because they are all to the power 1/2. So, I don't know how to move from there

Comment: @John: Do you know big $O$ and small $o$ notations?

Comment: Not really...I presumed that O(x) just represents the remaining terms

Comment: So, this is what they mean to make things precise. In general, what you are doing is correct and depends on what you have been taught in the class if you are taking a course.

Comment: My instructor uses LCT comparing it to x-x^3/3!.(which I don't get why because it makes things more complicated specially to find the limit.) If I included the o notation, doesn't that limit my capacity to deduce the final result because (a+b)^1/2 is not equal to a^1/2? Is there another way?

Comment: @John: Notice that, no body has said what you are doing is wrong. All what they said is to make things more precise, so you know what you are doing. So, that's why I asked you about the big and small O. I recommand to have a look at them so you can understand what $\sim$ means.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)!!  Just to be on the save side, I should include the landau symbol to keep track of how many terms I need and to be more precise.

Comment: @John: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

From the power series expansion of $\sin x$, we conclude that for $0\lt x\le 1$, we have
$$\sin x\lt x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}.$$
Thus 
$$\sin x \lt x-x^3\left(\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{120}\right).$$
It follows that 
$$n^{-1/2}-\sin(n^{-1/2})\gt \frac{19}{120}n^{-3/2},$$
and therefore if $a_n$ is the $n$-th term of our series, then 
$$a_n \gt \left(\frac{19}{120}\right)^{1/2}\frac{1}{n^{3/4}}.$$
By Comparison, our series diverges.

**Remark:** The analysis in the OP focused immediately on the right thing, the $x^3$ term in the power series of $\sin x$.  In many contexts the analysis would be sufficient. The difference $n^{-1/2}-\sin(n^{-1/2})$ "behaves like" $n^{-3/2}$, so $a_n$ behaves like $n^{-3/4}$, which goes to $0$ too slowly for convergence.

Once one **knows** that the intuitive argument can be fleshed out to give a full proof, there is no need to give the details. However, at this stage, part of the point is to acquire enough experience so that later one can legitimately leave out details.